# The "--templatePath" option requires a value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, way-generators

Every time I try to run `php artisan generate:scaffold article --fields="title:string, content:text`, it asks me `Do you want me to create a Article model? [yes|no]`, so I type `yes`, but after that it shows this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The "--templatePath" option requires a value.

generate:scaffold [--fields[="..."]] resource
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-install laravel, and it works :D !! Actually I don't know what was the problem but it works.